# Updating the product image based on thumbnail img using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've developing e-commerce site similar to amazon and in product detail page,when I click on thumbnail image on the left side it should update the right side image.

The problem is on first loading, the default image is not shown but when I click on the thumbnail its getting updated.Is there any way to show the first image of the thumbnail on first render?

The images are dynamic and is based on sequence order, filecatcode etc.

eg : mycompany.com/GetAppImage/?id=7&&filecatcode=F001&&sequence="1"

```
useEffect(() => {
    setProductImgSrc(
      getAllImagesBySeq(productData.prodId, productData.noOfImages, true)
    );
  }, [productData]);
const [productImgUrl , setProductImgUrl] = useState()
        const handleThumbImg = (src) =>{
            setProductImgUrl(src)
    }
        
        
        <div className="flex-row w-2/12 product-thumbnails cursor-pointer">
                        {(productImgSrc.thumbnailImgs || []).map((src) => {
                          return <img src={src} className="w-full object-contain" onClick={()=>handleThumbImg(src)}/>;
                        })}
                      </div>
          }
        
        <div className="flex-row w-10/12 product-Main-img ml-6">
                         <img src={productImgUrl} className="w-full object-contain" />
                      </div>
```

Comment: Your `useState()` is empty. replace it with `useState(productImgSrc.thumbnailImgs[0])`

Comment: I cannot access this because I'm setting the image value inside useeffect.

Comment: then inside useEffect call `Promise.resolve(returnFirstImageHere).then(firstImg => handleThumbImg(firstImg))`. You also may want to post the full snippet.

Comment: Updated the question with useffect codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve(setProductImgSrc(
      getAllImagesBySeq(productData.prodId, productData.noOfImages, true)
    ))
    .then(() => productImgSrc.thumbnailImgs.length > 0 ? setProductImgUrl(productImgSrc.thumbnailImgs[0]) : console.log("thumbnailImgs is empty"))
  }, [productData]);
const [productImgUrl , setProductImgUrl] = useState()
        const handleThumbImg = (src) =>{
            setProductImgUrl(src)
    }
        
        
        <div className="flex-row w-2/12 product-thumbnails cursor-pointer">
                        {(productImgSrc.thumbnailImgs || []).map((src) => {
                          return <img src={src} className="w-full object-contain" onClick={()=>handleThumbImg(src)}/>;
                        })}
                      </div>
          }
        
        <div className="flex-row w-10/12 product-Main-img ml-6">
                         <img src={productImgUrl} className="w-full object-contain" />
                      </div>
```

I would consider refactoring this code btw.